# Adding image to label without using file path

Tags: java, netbeans

I have imported a few images in my Netbeans Java project. I want to set one of them as a label's icon when I click a button. I don't want to use the path of the image in the code.

Please help me.

Comment: what ide are you using? Netbeans?

Comment: __(I don't want to use the path of the image in the code.)__
why so?

Comment: You could set the path element of the images as a static variable, that way, if it changes, you only need to change it in one place

Comment: @joey, what i want is that when i click a button, the particular image should be set as the label's icon. Suppose i use the images's path on my system and i run the project on another system, then it will fail. In simple words, i want to make the setting of image icon path independent.

Comment: If you run in some other system, you have to paste the image in your project.See my answer. `getClass().getResource("/yourImageName.jpg")` Will do it for you.Ask for EG if you want.But its better if you can make your own efforts from here.

Comment: @Nitesh, yes m using nb 7.2

Comment: @joey, i have not 'imported' the image in my source of JFrame (i.e. using 'import' keyword), i have just added to the package of my project. will this code still work?

Comment: Yeah! thats what!  Its fine like that.It will work.

Comment: Try, if you can't make it out, feel free to post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have imported images in your *project* then use :

```
myJLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/yourImageName.jpg")));
```

And enclose it in the [actionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) block of that button.

Refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) to know how to use `Jbutton`.

Comment: +1 for the wonderful info. Related info is also present on this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9864267/1057230).

Comment: Thanks Joey ! Figured it out though :)